# Set the '{' to go near the closing ')' in visual studio code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

this may be a stupid question but i recently switched from atom to visual studio code and i'm obsessed with the fact that vsc automatically write the { char on the bottom of a function, how can i change this setting?
Couldn't find anything on google so ye.

How i want it to be:

```
int main () {
    idk();
    return 0;
}
```

How it is:

```
int main () 
{
    idk();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about VS code, but on devstudio you go to Tools -> Options, expand "Text Editor" ->"C/C++" -> "Formatting" -> "New Lines".  It's under "Position of open braces for functions."

Comment: For historical reasons, preferred style in every C and C++ codebase I've ever seen is to put the open curly brace of a function definition on its own line, even if all other open braces are "cuddled". I recommend you get used to it now.

Comment: Tbh i'm used to put the open bracket on the same line, in vsc there is an option for autoformatting so if i know where the option to change the formatting of that bracket is i can just copy my code on another file and auto format it to have the open bracket on a new line, if i have to share it or something. Also i usually see the open bracket on the same line of the definition of that function in online's examples/stackoverflow questions so i guess it's the usual formatting